# Converting XML file to a data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

Using R(3.0.1) in Win7

I have been trying for a long time to convert an xml file (sample below) into a data frame and have been really struggling.  I have read through a number of links on SO already and found some useful stuff to get me started such as `xmlTreeParse` and `xmlToDataFrame` in package `XML` and have tried following some of the suggestions from those.  However, I have not been able to even come close to being able to do this. My major limitation here is that I know very little on XML files. I have read up on some of the basics of xml structure but this does not appear to me to be a simple format.

Looking for any help or suggestions that anyone may have.

The XML file does open in excel with no intervention but unfortunately I need to be able to read in hundreds of these things so saving from excel to .csv before parsing in R is not really an option.

SAMPLE Portion of XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:es="SpecificAttributes.13.06.xsd"
    xmlns:un="utranNrm.xsd" xmlns:xn="genericNrm.xsd"
    xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
<fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.615 V4.5" vendorName=""/>
<configData dnPrefix="Undefined">
    <xn:SubNetwork id="ONRM_ROOT_MO_R">
        <xn:SubNetwork id="NC_CLIN">
            <xn:MeContext id="testsite1">
                <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataSystemFunctions</xn:vsDataType>
                            <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                            <es:vsDataSystemFunctions/>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataLicensing</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataLicensing/>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCapacityLicenses</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataCapacityLicenses/>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licenseCapacityConnectedUsers>150</es:licenseCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licenseStateConnectedUsers>1</es:licenseStateConnectedUsers>
                                <es:capacityUnitConnectedUsers>Number of Connected Users</es:capacityUnitConnectedUsers>
                                <es:keyIdConnectedUsers>CXC4010608</es:keyIdConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licConnectedUsersPercentileConf>90</es:licConnectedUsersPercentileConf>
                                <es:gracePeriodActive>false</es:gracePeriodActive>
                                <es:gracePeriodAvailable>true</es:gracePeriodAvailable>
                                <es:gracePeriodOriginalLicenseLimit>75</es:gracePeriodOriginalLicenseLimit>
                                <es:gracePeriodTimeLeft>146</es:gracePeriodTimeLeft>
                                </es:vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                </xn:ManagedElement>
            </xn:MeContext>
            <xn:MeContext id="testsite2">
                <xn:ManagedElement id="1">
                    <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                        <xn:attributes>
                            <xn:vsDataType>vsDataSystemFunctions</xn:vsDataType>
                            <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                            <es:vsDataSystemFunctions/>
                        </xn:attributes>
                        <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                            <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataLicensing</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataLicensing/>
                            </xn:attributes>
                            <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCapacityLicenses</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataCapacityLicenses/>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                <xn:VsDataContainer id="1">
                                <xn:attributes>
                                <xn:vsDataType>vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers</xn:vsDataType>
                                <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>SpecificAttributes.13.06</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>
                                <es:vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licenseCapacityConnectedUsers>200</es:licenseCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licenseStateConnectedUsers>1</es:licenseStateConnectedUsers>
                                <es:capacityUnitConnectedUsers>Number of Connected Users</es:capacityUnitConnectedUsers>
                                <es:keyIdConnectedUsers>CXC4010608</es:keyIdConnectedUsers>
                                <es:licConnectedUsersPercentileConf>90</es:licConnectedUsersPercentileConf>
                                <es:gracePeriodActive>false</es:gracePeriodActive>
                                <es:gracePeriodAvailable>true</es:gracePeriodAvailable>
                                <es:gracePeriodOriginalLicenseLimit>0</es:gracePeriodOriginalLicenseLimit>
                                <es:gracePeriodTimeLeft>0</es:gracePeriodTimeLeft>
                                </es:vsDataCapacityConnectedUsers>
                                </xn:attributes>
                                </xn:VsDataContainer>
                            </xn:VsDataContainer>
                        </xn:VsDataContainer>
                    </xn:VsDataContainer>
                </xn:ManagedElement>
            </xn:MeContext>
        </xn:SubNetwork>
    </xn:SubNetwork>
</configData>
<fileFooter dateTime="2014-03-17T06:00:19Z"/>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

## **UPDATE:**

So I would still like to find the right way to do this with package `XML` but for now I used read.csv to read the all the lines in the xml file into R.  Then using a simple for loop to pull out just the most critical parts I am interested in.

```
test<-read.csv("C:/TEMP/file.xml")

parsedXML<-data.frame("SITE"=seq(0,100000, 1), "DATE"=-9999, "GPACTIVE"=-9999, "GPLEFT"=-9999)
parsedXML$ENODEB<--9999

row=0

for (i in 1:length(test[,1]))
  { 


    if(test[i,1]=="                </xn:MeContext>")
    {
      row=row+1
      i=i+1
      parsedXML$SITE[row]<-substr(test[i,1], 34, nchar(as.character(test[i,1]))-1)

      i=i+30
      parsedXML$GPACTIVE[row]<-substr(test[i,1], 59, nchar(as.character(test[i,1]))-23)

      i=i+3
      parsedXML$GPLEFT[row]<-substr(test[i,1], 61, nchar(as.character(test[i,1]))-25)

    }

  }

parsedXML$DATE<-substr(test[length(test[,1])-1,], 26, 44)## fill in the date of the file

parsedXMLfinal<-parsedXML[parsedXML$ENODEB!=-9999,]## remove unused rows

parsedXMLfinal2<-parsedXMLfinal[parsedXMLfinal$ENODEB!="",]## remove any blanks
```

It's not elegant by any means but provides me with something like this:

```
ENODEB     DATE                   GPACTIVE   GPLEFT
testsite1  2014-03-17T06:00:19Z   false      146
testsite2  2014-03-17T06:00:19Z   false      0
```

Comment: Is it an excel file?  You may be looking to use the wrong tools here. R has functionality with excel files.

Comment: No... it is an XML file that I am trying to convert to a data frame... I have used excel to open one of the sample XML files I have just to make sure it is a valid XML file.

Comment: My point here is that you could go from XML to Excel to R potentially.  If you can quickly and easily save these XML files to Excel then we can easily do this.  If not, there may be an issue with how your XML is presented here.  Have you tried `xmlToList()`?

Comment: I see what you are saying and I understand...if I only had a few files I would do it that way... unfortunately I have several hundred of these things to parse!  I did try `xmlToList` but it only gives 2 entries in the list because of the way this xml file is structured.

Comment: Can your try this with your xml files? `write(sampleXmlFile, file="fileName.xlsx")` Then see if they open as Excel files.

Comment: Could you also show what output you'd like to see from your example? I'm having trouble seeing where you might get rows and columns to make a tabular format - its a tag soup!

Comment: Your sample is not well-formed XML; please include a complete sample (or a link to same) that can actually be opened in Excel. When I copy your "sample", save it as `sample.xml` and try to open it in Excel, it fails.

Comment: Thanks guys.... I have put the file on jumpshare here [link](http://jmp.sh/JHohy3I).  I tried opening in excel just to make sure and it worked.  Although it did not have a schema so excel created one.

Comment: Spacedman --- you are right, it is a TAG SOUP which is why I think I am struggling with this so much.  I have gotten easier test examples to work but I am just not seeing this.  I would really like the rows and columns to be formatted the way excel does it when you open the XML file with excel

Comment: iShouldUseAName---- I think I see where you are going with the `write(sampleXmlFile, file="fileName.xlsx")`.... I did give it a try but no go.... it doesn't appear to appreciate the object type